# What value do i pass in Input(shape=...) in keras

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Suppose I have a numpy array with `shape = (1303, 3988, 1)`. What value do I need to pass to `Input()` so that my ai learns or do I need it, do I need to reshape it?

Comment: To what `Input()` of which `neural-network`, and what this `numpy` question has to do with `artificial-intelligence`?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your data is 1303 instances of vectors size (3988,1).

The answer depend on the layer goes after the input:

If you feed it after to Conv1D layer so the input layer should be:

```
Input(3988,1)
```

Otherwise you should squeeze the layer with:

```
np.squeeze(your_numpy_array)
```

or just flatten the input after the first layer:

```
  x=Input(3988,1)
  x=Flatten()(x)
```